# Running python code from standard Cocoa application

Tags: python, cocoa, macos, pyobjc

I have an XCode project built as a Cocoa single document application (it's not a Python-Cocoa application, that is not what I want).

All the documentation I found assumes I want to create a Cocoa application with code written in Python and this is not the case - I want a standard Cocoa application that calls a method out of a Python class.

Can I use PyObjC to run python code from a file without replacing the Cocoa standard main.c with a main.py file?

Later edit: I am aware of Python.framework but as far as I can tell I can only send parameters to PyRun_SimpleFile through the environment - I'd like to use the bridge directly to exchange data with the python code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A google search for [embed python objective C](http://www.google.com/search?q=embed+python+objective+C), returns a few links that might be of interest, in particular:

- http://blog.alienoverlord.com/?p=14
- http://blog.tlensing.org/2008/11/04/embedding-python-in-a-cocoa-application/

Comment: I've looked at the first link a couple of days ago, but I was to blind to see it did indeed describe the solution to my problem. Thanks.